# How to use text strip() function?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I can strip numerics but not alpha characters:

```
>>> text
'132abcd13232111'

>>> text.strip('123')
'abcd'
```

Why the following is not working?

```
>>> text.strip('abcd')
'132abcd13232111'
```

Comment: Please do not ask questions that are easily addressed by [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). You are expected to have done some research, and looking at documentation for some method you don't understand is the *bare minimum*.  Using StackOverflow should be a last resort.

Comment: My bad. I skimmed the doc so I even skipped the part mentioning leading/trailing chars.  I will heed your advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is simple and stated in the [documentation of `strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
str.strip([chars])

Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. 
The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.
```

`'abcd'` is neither leading nor trailing in the string `'132abcd13232111'` so it isn't stripped.

Comment: @nfnneil Because the numbers at the beginning and end of the string match the set of characters provided as the argument to `strip`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a few examples to [Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43214349/3846228), according to [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) docs:

- Return a copy of the string with the **leading** and **trailing** characters removed.
- The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.
- If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.
- The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

So it doesn't matter if it's a digit or not, the main reason your second code didn't worked **as you expected**, is because the term "abcd" was located in the middle of the string.

---

**Example1:**

```
s = '132abcd13232111'
print(s.strip('123'))
print(s.strip('abcd'))
```

**Output:**

```
abcd
132abcd13232111
```

---

**Example2:**

```
t = 'abcd12312313abcd'
print(t.strip('123'))
print(t.strip('abcd'))
```

**Output:**

```
abcd12312313abcd
12312313
```